# Discrete math - Set theory - Power sets - Prove question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following sentence:
$$ A\subseteq B \lor B\subseteq A \to P(A\cup B) = P(A) \cup P(B) $$
I need to use 2 ways to prove that: first is the normal way, and second is by proving the opposite way, for example:
$$ P(A\cup B) = P(A) \cup P(B) \to A\subseteq B \lor B\subseteq A $$

Comment: What is P? Set function?

Comment: Power set of A  = P(A)

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some effort and tell us exactly where you get stuck.

Comment: "I need to use 2 ways to prove that: first is the normal way, and second is by proving the opposite way"  What the heck does that mean?  Do you mean you need to prove this is an if and only if statement?

Answer (score 1):

If $A \subset B \lor B \subset A$ then either $A \cup B = A$ or $A \cup B = B$.

If $A \subset B$ and $A\cup B = B$ then any subset, $X\subset A$ (or in other words $X \in P(A)$) will contain only elements of $A$, which in turn are elements of $B$ so $X\subset B$ so $P(A) \subset P(B)$ and so $P(A)\cup P(B) = P(B) = P(A\cup B)$.

Similarly if $B\subset A$ then $P(A)\cup P(B) = P(A) = P(A \cup B)$.

So that is the "if direction".

If $P(A\cup B) = P(A)\cup P(B)$:  Let's take a set $X=\{a,b\}$ where $a$ is an arbitrary element from $A$ and $b$ is an arbitrary element from $B$.  (If either $A$ or $B$ is empty the result is trivial.)

$X \in P(A\cup B)$.  So $X \in P(A) \cup P(B)$ so $X \in P(A)$ or $X\in P(B)$.  If $X \in P(A)$ then $b \in A$.  As $b$ was arbitrary $B\subset A$.   Likewise if $X\in P(B)$ then $a \in B$ and $A \subset B$.

So that is the "only if" direction.